# set input to AM PM in django timefield

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, timefield

i want to allow users to be able to choose between am and pm with my django timefield

Currently if I enter:

> 11:00 AM

,  i get a form error: "Enter a valid time."

If I enter:

> 11:00

the form validates with no problem.

I also tried:

```
class RemindersForm(forms.ModelForm):

    remdinder = forms.TimeField(input_formats='%H:%M %p',)

    class Meta:
        model = NotificationPreference
        fields = (
                  'reminder', 
                  )
```

This changes the input format to:

> 11:00:00

and still gives me the above validation error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14):

I was searching for a similar answer and I didn't find a suitable one for `models.TimeField`, so, the easiest solution that I found for doing this site wide would be to setting in your ***settings.py*** the following global variable:

```
TIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%I:%M %p',]
```

I hope this helps someone.

To use other formats see:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Comment: Really useful and DRY.

Comment: By this method, we are still not able to use AM or PM in input field and we have to use 24-hour clock to provide the input though AM or PM is stored in the database.

Answer (score 10):

To get a 12hr time format you would use the following:

For input (This is the list of formats Django uses in validation):

```
field = TimeField(input_formats=('%I:%M %p',...,...))
```

For output (This is the format Django will use to display time values):

```
field = TimeField(widget=TimeInput(format='%I:%M %p'))
```

The %I indicates a 12 hour clock format whereas the %H indicates a 24 hour clock format.

Additionally, the default list of input_formats can be found in each locales formats.py file. Django uses the first format in the input_formats list as the default output format for time fields.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do some thing like this in forms.py

```
field = DateTimeField(input_formats='%H:%M %p',...)
```

Comment: The time now shows up as 14:30:00 for me. Is this format correct?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-TIME_INPUT_FORMATS), and [python's datetime docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior), it should work if you change the time input settings to:

```
TIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%I:%M %p',)
```

Comment: Are you saying to add this to the form field constructor?  Also, this time format shows up as 14:30:00 for me.  Is this format correct?

Comment: I'm a bit late with this comment but there is no such thing as 14:30 AM to begin with.

Comment: This answer worked for me except instead of `%H`, change it to `%I`. Like so:

`TIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ( '%I:%M %p',  )`